# Fill multidimensional array elements with 0's

Tags: c++

I have a 2d and i want to set the elements to zero without looping all the elements

```
int a[100][200];
```

I can't initialize them at point of declaration.

Comment: Why can't you initialise them at the point of declaration?

Comment: Are you trying to declare them in a class?

Answer (score 31):

Try

```
int a[100][200] = {{0}};
```

If you initialize some (but not all) of the elements, the rest will be initialized to zero.  Here, you are only explicitly initializing the first element of the first sub-array and the compiler is taking care of the rest.

Comment: +1 `= {0}` should also work, but this will probably avoid compiler warnings better.

Comment: And to cut it even shorter, C++ allows `= {};`.

Comment: Does this work for arrays with more than 2 dimensions (assuming correct number of parenthesis)?

Comment: @101 - yes.  You're explicitly initializing the first entry in the first dimension, and the rest gets done automatically (no matter the dimensions).

Answer (score 18):

Try `memset(a,0,sizeof(a));`

This simply overwrites the memory used by the array with 0 bytes. Don't do this for user-defined data types unless you really know what you do. There's also `std::fill` and `std::fill_n`, which is more C++ish (but not the easiest way here).

Comment: Even for non-user defined data-types, this may generate unexpected results. Data member-pointers are an example that use a non-0x0 null-pointer encoding in the C++-ABI used by GCC and Clang ("Itanium ABI") - they use all-1 bits. For "int" this should be fine though.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `sizeof(a) * sizeof(int)` here?

Comment: No, sizeof on the array returns the correct size in bytes, so there is no need to multiply by the int size.

Answer (score 7):

For C++, you can use the std:fill method from the algorithm header.

```
int a[x][y];
std::fill(a[0], a[0] + x * y, 0);
```

So, in your case, you could use this:

```
int a[100][200];
std::fill(a[0], a[0] + 100 * 200, 0);
```

Of course, the 0 could be changed for any int value.

Answer (score 6):

C++ allows multidimensional arrays to be iterated entirely through by a base-element pointer. So you can use `std::fill` and pass it the very first nonarray element

```
std::fill(a[0] + 0, a[99] + 100, 0);
```

In C this is formally not allowed, and you would need to iterate through each sub-array separately, because iterating beyond the first subarray's past-the-end pointer causes undefined behavior in C. Nontheless, in practice this still works.

Comment: Is this still true? (Was it ever?)

Answer (score 3):

What exactly does "I can't initialize them at point of declaration" mean? "Don't know how to"? Or "can't modify the code there"?

The C++ language has a feature that initializes the entire array to 0 at the point of declaration

```
int a[100][100] = {};
```

(note, no explicit `0` is really necessary between the `{}`). Can you use it or not?

If you can't, then your options are: use the `memset`-hack, 1D-reinterpretation-hack or set each element explicitly by iterating through the array(s) (with or without the help fo `std::fill`).

Comment: Initialization at declaration is forbidden, for example, when `goto` or `switch` jumps over the declaration into the variable's scope.

Answer (score 3):

Many answers used pointer arithmetic with `fill`. This can be done simpler:

```
int a[N][K];
fill(a[0], a[N], 0);
```

Basically, `a[N]` is a first memory address after the multi-dimensional array, no matter how many dimensions there are. This works too:

```
int a[N][K][L][M];
fill(**a[0], **a[N], 0);
```

The asterisks here dereferences the pointers down to `int*` type (the array brackets dereferences `int****` to `int***`, the two asterisks does the rest of the job).

Answer (score 2):

`memset(a, 0, 100 * 200 * sizeof(int));` ought to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If this array is declared at file scope, or at function scope but with 'static', then it is automatically initialized to zero for you, you don't have to do anything.  This is only good for *one* initialization, at program startup; if you need to reset it you have to code that yourself.  I would use `memset` for that.

If it's declared at function scope without static, you need to use `memset`, or an explicit initializer - a single `= { 0 }` is enough, you don't need to write out all 200<sup>2</sup> zeroes like someone else suggested.

Comment: Should also add that the semantics of static variables vs. variables with non-static declaration are very different. Variables declared as static inherently declare a state; this might not be what the OP wants. I do agree with the memset approach (or explicit initializer).

Answer (score 0):

The `memset` approach mentioned (`memset(a,0,sizeof(a));`) will work, but what about doing it the C++ way (per your tag), and using vector?

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > a;
a.assign(100, std::vector<int>(200));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this solution and it worked.

```
int arr[100][200];

for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<200; j++) (arr[i][j] = 0);

for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<200; j++) cout << (arr[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
int a[100][200]={0};
```

This will initialize all the elements of the array with 0

Answer (score -1):

Since the size is well-defined, all you need is the trailing parenthesis...

```
int a[100][200]();
```