# How to use memset or fill_n to initialize a dynamic two dimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays, memset

I have a 2D array created dynamically.

```
int **abc = new int*[rows];

for (uint32_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    abc[i] = new int[cols];
}
```

I want to fill the array with some value (say 1). I can loop over each item and do it.

But is there a simpler way. I am trying to use `memset` and `std::fill_n` as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586774/fill-multidimensional-array-elements-with-0s).

```
std::fill_n(abc, rows * cols, 1);
memset(abc, 1, rows * cols * sizeof(int));
```

Using memset crashes my program. Using fill_n gives a compile error.

```
invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Dropping back to C might be an option: `int (*abc)[cols] = malloc(rows*sizeof(*abc)); memset(abc, 1, rows*sizeof(*abc));` is legal C since C99, but won't be possible in C++ any time soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use `vector`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> abc(rows, std::vector<int>(cols, 1));
```

You cannot use `std::fill_n` or `memset` on `abc` directly, it simply will not work. You can only use either on the sub-arrays:

```
int **abc = new int*[rows];

for (uint32_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    abc[i] = new int[cols];
    std::fill_n(abc[i], cols, 1);
}
```

Or make the whole thing single-dimensional:

```
int *abc = new int[rows * cols];
std::fill_n(abc, rows*cols, 1);
```

Or I guess you could use [`std::generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) in combination with `std::fill_n`, but this just seems confusing:

```
int **abc = new int*[rows];
std::generate_n(abc, rows, [cols]{
    int* row = new int[cols];
    std::fill_n(row, cols, 1);
    return row;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that your main problem here is that you don't have an array of `int` values. You have an array of pointers to `int`s.

You probably should start with `int* abc = new int[rows * cols];` and work from there, if I understand what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 2):

Just use with * inside the loop you already have:

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    abc[i] = new int[cols];
    std::fill_n(*(abc+i), cols, sizeof(int));
}
```

fill_n don't know where the memory maps the new int array, so you must be carefully coding that way.

I recommend to read:
[A proper way to create a matrix in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618511/a-proper-way-to-create-a-matrix-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already got good, workable answers to solve your problem, I want to add just two pointers left and right from the standard path ;-)

a) is just a link to the documentation of [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html)

and b) is something I *don't recommend you use*, but it might help you to understand what you've initially tried. And since your profile shows `visual studio` tags, you *might* come in contact with something like this in the win32 api. If that is the case the documentation usually tells you not to use free()/LocalFree()/... on the elements and the "outer" pointer-pointer but to use a specialized function.
(note: I'm not trying to make this code look pretty or clever; it's a mishmash of c and a little c++-ish junk ;-))

```
const std::size_t rows = 3, cols =4; 

int main()
{   
    std::size_t x,y;
    // allocate memory for 0...rows-1 int* pointers _and_ cols*rows ints
    int **abc = (int**)malloc( (rows*sizeof(int*)) + cols*rows*sizeof(int) );

    // the memory behind abc is large enough to hold the pointers for abc[0...rows-1]
    // + the actual data when accessing abc[0...rows-1][0....cols-1]
    int* data = (int*)((abc+rows));
    // data now points to the memory right after the int*-pointer array
    // i.e. &(abc[0][0]) and data should point to the same location when we're done:
    // make abc[0] point to the first row (<-> data+(cols*0)), abc[1] point the second row (<-> data+(cols*1).... 
    for(y=0;y<rows; y++) {
        abc[y] = &(data[y*cols]);
    }

    // now you can use abc almost like a stack 2d array
    for(y=0; y<rows; y++) {
        for (x=0; x<cols; x++) {
            abc[y][x] = 127;
        }
    }

    // and -since the memory block is continuos- you can also (with care) use memset
    memset(&abc[0][0], 1, sizeof(int)*rows*cols);

    // and with equal care ....
    std::fill_n( &(abc[0][0]), rows*cols, 127);

    // and get rid of the whole thing with just one call to free
    free(abc);

    return 0;
}
```